# Windows Azure, New VM Role: How to delete an attached disk to a deleted VM?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Does anyone know how can I delete a disk resource attached to a non-existent (deleted) virtual machine in the new portal of windows azure?

Answer (score 2):

You navigate to "Virtual Machines (1), then click on "Disks" (2), then select the non-used disk (3) and finally click on delete (4):

[image]

Or just any Azure Storage explorer (like [Cerebrata's Cloud Storage Studio](http://cerebrata.com/Products/CloudStorageStudio/), or [Azure Storage Explorer](http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/)) to delete from the storage account. It is a single blob after all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

It seems kinda of obvious, but after delete the VM where disks were originally attached, delete option for disk [4] is disabled. I also try, using [CloudXplorer](http://clumsyleaf.com/products/cloudxplorer) and  I received  the following error: CloudXplorer could not delete 'yyyy.vhd'. There is currently a lease on the blob and lease id was not specified.

Comment: I think that you now need to open a support ticket for this. Since, you can clearly see that Delete Disk is not disabled for mine "unattached" disk. As this feature is in Preview, I expect these kind of small issues.